# C++ printf WORD* (ToAscii)

Tags: c++, keyboard, ascii, printf

I am using hooks and I have a vkCode and a scanCode so I am using the command ToAscii() as such:

```
...
LPWORD wCharacter;
ToAscii(kbdStruct.vkCode, kbdStruct.scanCode, keyboard_state, wCharacter, 0);
```

So now wCharacter should hold the Ascii character right?

How can I print that out?

I tried: `printf(wCharacter);` but it says: "cannot convert 'WORD*' to 'const char*'"

What am I doing wrong? How do I print out a WORD*? Or was I doing the ToAscii command wrong?

Comment: I guarantee you that it does *not* say "const chart *". You're making stuff up. Don't do that. Post actual things that happen on your computer.

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo, updated :)

Comment: @KerrekSB Some people can't copy and paste so they hand-type error messages and make typos. It's not always "making stuff up".

Answer (score 1):

WORD nor ToAscii() is standard C++, so answering this is kind of tricky. However, there are two issues anyhow:

- printf() first argument should be a format string. You did not supply any.
- String is a sequence of characters terminated by a zero byte. If you want to print out a single character passed as a parameter, assuming that WORD is something int-ish, you can use "%c" format string.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get far with this, you are passing an uninitialized pointer to ToAscii().  Proper code should look like this:

```
WORD wCharacter[2];
int len = ToAscii(kbdStruct.vkCode, kbdStruct.scanCode, keyboard_state, wCharacter, 0);
if (len == 1) printf("%c", wCharacter[0]);
if (len == 2) printf("%c", wCharacter[1]);
```

This ought to compile and work, somewhat.  In practice you cannot get this reliable.  The *keyboard_state* variable you pass should be the keyboard state of the process that owns the foreground window.  And you should pay attention to the keyboard layout that's active for that process (see ToAsciiEx).  That cannot be made to work with a low-level keyboard hook.  A keyboard logger must use a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook instead to intercept WM_CHAR messages (I think, never wrote one).  **Much** harder to get right, that requires a DLL that can be injecting into other processes.  You are of course inventing a wheel, buy and not build is the best advice.  Also would make your users a bit more comfortable about your intentions.

Comment: Okay, thanks that appears to compile. Works fine too, except for special chars like !"£$%^&*(), shift, enter, backspace etc. Do you have any idea how I can make it print those out? Thanks.

Comment: That's the keyboard_state I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

**LPWORD wCharacter;**
is a Long Pointer to a word.   Word here as an integer of two bytes not a "word" in a sentence.  It's basically an int16.  printf would handle that as.

```
printf("%hd", *wCharacter );
```

1. where h spefifies a 16 bit value
2. d specifies an integer
3. *wCharacter is the dereferenced pointer or value of you int.

if you wanted your printed value to reflect it as unsigned

```
printf("%hu", *wCharacter );
```

unsigned hex

```
printf("%hx", *wCharacter );
```

unsigned hex with capital letters

```
printf("%hX", *wCharacter );
```

Now having said all that it's possible your WORD int is a Unicode character or two byte character as apposed to a normal 8 bit standard char.

In unicode if you are still representing standard ascii characters as apposed to some Arabic or Chinese characters you can translate the unicode character into a standard char
by ignoring the first byte.

```
LPWORD wCharacter;
char *pChar = (char*)wCharacter;

printf("%c", pChar[1]);
```

1. Declare pChar a pointer to an 8 bit value (char).
2. Set the pChar address to your WORD pointer.
3. Use the pChar pointer as an array and incremented it to the second
   byte [1];

This works if you aren't using international character set.